# Pandas way to make new column that index matches a key for all duplicate values in another column

Tags: python, pandas

What is the Pandas way to *make a new column* that finds and return any duplicate values in another column based on a single key?

The raw data is like this. Call it `MaterialsReport_df`:

[image]

Notice how my tag appears twice for the last two rows. I want to concatenate their sites in my final report. Generally, I also need to return whatever the site(s) are to match the tags which *already exist* in my final report called `BoxTrackingReport_df`, in the target column `All Box Tracked Sites`:

[image]

I'm currently creating a dictionary like `{tag, [site 1, site 2, site 3]}` and then iterating through the dictionary to return all possible sites:

```py
BoxTrackingReport_df['All Box Tracked Sites'] = [site_dict.get(x) for x in BoxTrackingReport_df['Tag']]
```

I thought there would be a simpler way because my dictionary code is torturous. My attempt at a Pandas way:

```py
BoxTrackingReport_df['All Box Tracked Sites'] = [x + "  " for x in MaterialsReport_df.loc[BoxTrackingReport_df['Tag'] == MaterialsReport_df['Tag'], ['Scoring Site Including X']]]
```

The attempt gave me this error:

```py
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

[Edited for detail]

Comment: `df[df.A.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('A')['B'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(name='All_boxed_site')`

Comment: `df.groupby('Tag')['Scoring Site...'].apply(' '.join)`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out with the help of everyone's answer especially from @anky_91

`df[df.A.duplicated(keep=False)].groupby('A')['B'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(name='All_boxed_site')` – anky_91 59 mins ago

This was my final solution:

```py
AllBoxSites_df = MaterialsReport_df.groupby('Tag')['Scoring Site Including X'].apply(' '.join).reset_index(name='All Box Tracked Sites')
BoxTrackingReport_df = pd.merge(BoxTrackingReport_df, AllBoxSites_df, how='left', left_on='Tag', right_on='Tag')
```

So I actually created a new df using `groupby` and then merged that to make sure the index match was applied.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `groupby()` with `.apply()`

```
df.groupby('Tag')['Scoring Site Including X'].apply(' '.join)
```

Comment: I did not see the answer in the comments lol. Anyway, that's how you should do it. :D

Comment: Thanks Joe. The thing is I'm using two dfs. How do I make sure that the `Tag` of the 2nd df matches the `Tag` of the current row of my 1st df?

Edited question for more details

Comment: Tried `BoxTrackingReport_df['All Box Tracked Sites'] = MaterialsReport_df.groupby(BoxTrackingReport_df['Tag'])['Scoring Site Including X'].apply(' '.join)` but returns NaNs

Comment: Hi yes, well do you really need two dfs though? If they have similar columns, concatenate the two of them into one master_df if you may. Then do the code above on it. If that is not allowed or there's other manipulation you need to do on one of them. Maybe create a copy of the second df to the first? I'll show the code later I'm just using mobile now. Lol.btw don't forget to upvote if an answer helped you. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I have used an example with tailored function as shown below.

Create dataframe:

````
import pandas as pd
df_data = pd.DataFrame({"tag": ["1", "2", "3","4", "4"], "nams":["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]}); df_data```

Apply function to groupby:
````

def join_with_space(x):
    return(" ".join(x))

df_data.groupby("tag")["nams"].agg(join_with_space)